# Apply CSS different styles to tables inside Bootstrap accordion

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a bootstrap accordion in a div (ID:avs4), each panel heading has a certain color and each panel body has a table with same class (avactr):

```css
#avs4 :nth-child(1) tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:first-child {
  background: #047AB7;
}

#avs4 :nth-child(2) tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:first-child {
  background: #42B77A;
}

#avs4 :nth-child(1) tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:first-child a,
#avs4 :nth-child(2) tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:first-child a {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="avs4">
    <div class="panel-group" id="avancesacorf" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" style="margin-bottom:0px;border-left: 1px solid #047ab7;border-right: 1px solid #047ab7;">
      <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top:0px;border-radius:0px;border:none;">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading16" style="padding: 0px;background: none;">
          <table class="table avelem" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;width:50%;">
                  <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#avancesacorf" href="#collapse16" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse16">Progress</a>
                </td>
                <td style="background:#FFF;text-align:center;">User 01</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse16" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading16" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
          <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0px;">
            <table class="table avactr" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width:50%;text-align:center;">Files</td>
                  <td style="background:#FFF;color:#000;text-align:center;"><a target="_blank" href="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/LuZN13YUT6mc73TJeIs4"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;margin-bottom:5px;"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> doc-prueba.docx</button></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="text-align:center;">Rate 01</td>
                  <td style="background:#FFF;color:#000;text-align:center;">5 / 5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="text-align:center;">Rate 02</td>
                  <td style="background:#FFF;color:#000;text-align:center;">300 / 300</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top:0px;border-radius:0px;border:none;">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading14" style="padding: 0px;background: none;">
          <table class="table avelem" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;width:50%;">
                  <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#avancesacorf" href="#collapse14" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse14">Progress</a>
                </td>
                <td style="background:#FFF;text-align:center;">User 02</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse14" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading14" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
          <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0px;">
            <table class="table avactr" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width:50%;text-align:center;">Files</td>
                  <td style="background:#FFF;color:#000;text-align:center;"><a target="_blank" href="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/twvU9uWSvvCWPh2jvuOQ"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;margin-bottom:5px;"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> modelo-doc.jpg</button></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="text-align:center;">Rate 01</td>
                  <td style="background:#FFF;color:#000;text-align:center;">1 / 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="text-align:center;">Rate 02</td>
                  <td style="background:#FFF;color:#000;text-align:center;">10 / 100</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to apply different styles for each table "avactr" class according to panel heading color, I tried to apply first table, for example, with this code:

```
#avs4 :nth-child(1) table.avactr tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:first-child {
 background: #047AB7;
  color: #FFF;
}

#avs4 :nth-child(1) table.avactr tbody tr:nth-child(2) td:first-child {
  background: #047AB7;
  color: #FFF;
}

#avs4 :nth-child(1) table.avactr tbody tr:nth-child(3) td:first-child {
  background: #047AB7;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

But it doesn't work, How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The css pseudo-class `:nth-child(1)` wasn't working when it was just dangling by itself but seems like it will work the way you expect if you tell it what type of element you are targeting as in `.panel:nth-child(1)`.

```css
#avs4 .panel:nth-child(1) tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:first-child {
  background: #047AB7;
}

#avs4 .panel:nth-child(2) tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:first-child {
  background: #42B77A;
}

#avs4 .panel:nth-child(1) tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:first-child a,
#avs4 .panel:nth-child(2) tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:first-child a {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="avs4">
    <div class="panel-group" id="avancesacorf" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" style="margin-bottom:0px;border-left: 1px solid #047ab7;border-right: 1px solid #047ab7;">
      <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top:0px;border-radius:0px;border:none;">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading16" style="padding: 0px;background: none;">
          <table class="table avelem" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;width:50%;">
                  <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#avancesacorf" href="#collapse16" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse16">Progress</a>
                </td>
                <td style="background:#FFF;text-align:center;">User 01</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse16" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading16" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
          <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0px;">
            <table class="table avactr" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width:50%;text-align:center;">Files</td>
                  <td style="background:#FFF;color:#000;text-align:center;"><a target="_blank" href="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/LuZN13YUT6mc73TJeIs4"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;margin-bottom:5px;"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> doc-prueba.docx</button></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="text-align:center;">Rate 01</td>
                  <td style="background:#FFF;color:#000;text-align:center;">5 / 5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="text-align:center;">Rate 02</td>
                  <td style="background:#FFF;color:#000;text-align:center;">300 / 300</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top:0px;border-radius:0px;border:none;">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading14" style="padding: 0px;background: none;">
          <table class="table avelem" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;width:50%;">
                  <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#avancesacorf" href="#collapse14" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse14">Progress</a>
                </td>
                <td style="background:#FFF;text-align:center;">User 02</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse14" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading14" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
          <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0px;">
            <table class="table avactr" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width:50%;text-align:center;">Files</td>
                  <td style="background:#FFF;color:#000;text-align:center;"><a target="_blank" href="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/twvU9uWSvvCWPh2jvuOQ"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-right:5px;margin-bottom:5px;"><i class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></i> modelo-doc.jpg</button></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="text-align:center;">Rate 01</td>
                  <td style="background:#FFF;color:#000;text-align:center;">1 / 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="text-align:center;">Rate 02</td>
                  <td style="background:#FFF;color:#000;text-align:center;">10 / 100</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```